# IE 6 & IE 7 Z-Index Problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

http://madisonlane.businesscatalyst.com

I'm trying to get the div#sign-post to sit above the div#bottom. This works fine in all browsers except IE6 & IE7. Can anyone see what the problem is here?

Also IE6 is displaying an additional 198px to the top of div#bottom.

Comment: Ironically it works great in IE8

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Agree with validator comment - validating usually helps. But, if it doesn't heres a few pointers for z-index in IE:

1) elements who's z-index you're manipulating should be on the same level ie. you should be setting the z-index of #bottom and #body

if this is not feasible then

2) IE sometimes wont apply the z-index correctly unless the elements ou are applying it to have a `position:relative`. Try applying that property to #bottom and #body (or #signpost)

let me know how that works out

Darko

Comment: I beleive this is due to the well known bug fixed by adding "position:relative" to the stylesheet.

Comment: This behavior is because IE6/7 start a new stacking order for every element that has the position:relative. http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Answer (score 152):

Most of the answers here are wrong; some work, but not for the reason they state. Here is some explanation.

This is how z-index should work according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index):

- you can give a `z-index` value to any element; if you don't, it defaults to `auto`
- positioned elements (that is, elements with a `position` attribute different from the default `static`) with a `z-index` different from `auto` create a new *stacking context*. Stacking contexts are the "units" of overlapping; one stacking context is either completely above the another (that is, every element of the first is above any element of the second) or completely below it.
- inside the same stacking context, the *stack level* of the elements is compared. Elements with an explicit `z-index` value have that value as a stack level, other elements inherit from their parents. The element with the higher stack level is displayed on top. When two elements have the same stack level, generally the one which is later in the DOM tree is painted on top. (More complicated rules apply if they have a different `position` attribute.)

In other words, when two elements have `z-index` set, in order to decide which will show on top, you need to check if they have any positioned parents which also have `z-index` set. If they don't, or the parents are common, the one with the higher z-index wins. If they do, you need to compare the parents, and the `z-index` of the children is irrelevant.

So the `z-index` decides how the element is placed compared to other children of its "stacking parent" (the closest ancestor with a `z-index` set and a `position` of `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`), but it doesn't matter when comparing to other elements; it is the stacking parent's `z-index` (or possibly the `z-index` of the stacking parent's stacking parent, et cetera) which counts. In a typical document where you use `z-index` only on a few elements like dropdown menus and popups, none of which contains the other, the stacking parent of all the elements which have a `z-index` is the whole document, and you can usually get away with thinking of the `z-index` as a global, document-level ordering.

The fundamental difference with IE6/7 is that positioned elements start new stacking contexts, whether they have `z-index` set or not. Since the elements which you would instinctively assign `z-index` values to are typically absolutely positioned and have a relatively positioned parent or close ancestor, this will mean that your `z-index`-ed elements won't be compared at all, instead their positioned ancestors will - and since those have no z-index set, document order will prevail.

As a workaround, you need to find out which ancestors are actually compared, and assign some z-index to them to restore the order you want (which will usually be reverse document order). Usually this is done by javascript - for a dropdown menu, you can walk through the menu containers or parent menu items, and assign them a `z-index` of 1000, 999, 998 and so on. Another method: when a popup or dropdown menu becomes visible, find all its relatively positioned ancestors, and give them an `on-top` class which has a very high z-index; when it becomes invisible again, remove the classes.

Comment: Thank you for solving a mystery for me! :)  I have had this issue with element ordering and each time I feel like I'm resorting to black magic to make it work.

Comment: Thank You! i have never understood the stacking order issue before. was always a mystery to me why sometimes it worked and sometimes it didnt.

Comment: In what circumstances will this method (adding z-index to relative parent) not work and is there another work around?

Comment: @DEfusion: IE6 has another bug related to vertical positioning; some elements (for example `<select>` or Flash) are sort of outside the document, and there is no way to position stuff above them via z-index. That is normally solved by putting an iframe between them and the popup.

Comment: Thanks! For a drop-down or pop-up type of widget that should always be on top of everything, using jQuery, this is really easy to fix. Call $(myWidget).parents().addClass('on-top') when opening the widget, and $(myWidget).parents().removeClass('on-top') when closing it.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Spent ages trying to debug this, (which in IE is an absolute pain) read your post and sorted it within minutes, excellent explanation as well!

Comment: really good answer which explains exactly the issue. My case was a datetimepicker in IE7, what I did was to add the calendar object to the body instead of the control container, and fixed it. The way I explain this, is because the calendar is in the body, then all roots are siblings therefore the zindex can be managed correctly since all other controls are within form, divs, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem and the fix I found (thanks to Quirksmode) was to give the direct parent of the node you are trying to set a z-index of it's own z-index that is at less than the z-index of the node you are trying to set.  Here is a quick example that should work in IE6

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #AlwaysOnTop {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
        width: 300px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 2;
      }
      #Header {
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="Header">
      <div id="AlwaysOnTop">This will always be on top</div>
    </div>
    <div id="Content">Some long amount of text to produce a scroll bar</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works because it places `#Header` higher than `#Content` (which is presumably a positioned element). The relation between the z-index of `#Header` and `#AlwaysOnTop` is irrelevant. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, I solved the problem with:

```
.header { 
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1001;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have some malformed HTML in there. I tried counting, and perhaps I lost count of the opening and closing tags, but it looks like div#container isn't closed. Try running your page through a validator (such as W3C's HTML Validator, or something)  and fixing some of the errors. That's helped me with these sorts of problems in the past. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had an ongoing problem displaying one layer above another. In my case I was programmatically creating two layers in Javascript, one for diaplaying a custom control and one for creating a full screen layer behind it. FF was fine, bu IE displayed the full screen layer always on top of everything else.

After numerous trawls over the interweb, trying everyone's suggestions, the only way I eventually get it working was to remove `position:` attributes from both layers, and tweak the `margin-top:` attribute until I got a satisfactory result.

A bit of a hash, but it works and it'll be fine until IE 8 sorts out all of the current bugs......

Answer (score 0):

the only reliable solution is, to put the top elements **below in the code and then push them over** the other stuff with absolute positioning.

e.g. Wordpress:
put the navigation in the footer file, but still inside the page wrapper.

might also bring some advantages for search engines, because they can directly start with the content, without crawling through the menu first...

UPDATE:
I need to correct myself. While putting the element below and then pushing it over is still the easiest way, there are certain cases when this is not possible in reasonable time. Then **you have to make sure that each and every parent element has some kind of positioning and some senseful z-index**. Then the z-index should work again even in IE7.