# IE7 z-index and stacking

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I've spent close to two days trying to solve a z-index/stacking problem in IE7 and I've admitted defeat and I'm hoping one of you geniuses can help me out!

If you go to http://learningseat.wpdemo.com.au/discover/#links in IE7 and click on What We Stand For or Where We're Going you will see that the Who We Work With and Who We Are links show on top of my lightbox.

I've tried to solve this issue by moving things around, adding position: relative and z-indexes to different elements but I've had no success with this at all.

I even tried using some of the jQuery tricks for z-index issues with IE but I've had no luck.

I've worked with another developer on this project and the code isn't too pretty but if anyone could help me with this problem I'd be forever grateful!

Thanks for your ideas and help!

Answer (score 0):

In [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3998006/249624), Tgr gives a pretty good explanation of how z-index is supposed to work and how IE 7 and earlier get it wrong.

What worked for me in my limited tinkering was the solution presented in the last paragraph of that answer.  First I removed the IE7-specific z-index values in your stylesheet, then I added a very high z-index value (9999) to the `.buttoninfo` that was clicked on.  In your code, you can add a class when the button is clicked, then remove it when popup is hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that post Cheran! That was awesome. I ended up doing some jQuery magic with z-indexes when the elements were clicked!