# Richfaces drag and drop - drag indicator not show when dragSrouce is inside PopupPanel in IE9

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, richfaces, z-index

I have a drag and drop inside a rch:popupPanel, and the drag indicator always appear behind the popup panel, and I dont know how to fix this, I try to this,

```
.rf-ind-drag.default{
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

but this only fix Chrome, but IE9 still suffer the same problem, does any one experience this problem before and know how to fix it?

Comment: It's hard to answer without seeing some JSF or preferably HTML. I don't use RichFaces extensively and can't tell from top of head what HTML it generates. jQuery/CSS users would have no idea what you're talking about without seeing concrete HTML. At least, positioning plays a role in stacking. To understand it better, carefully read http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex. In any case, this problem is known at RichFaces: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12527 and https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-8056 This answer is also pretty good: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3998006